# Can't pass the chosen data from the table rows in the modal to the parent view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a checkbox which whenever i check it, a modal popup will appear.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="inputNewBornKMC" value="inputNewBornKMC" id="inputNewBornKMCCheckbox"> New Born
```

I have no trouble loading the modal and doing a search query inside it, but i'm having a problem to pass the chosen data from the table rows in the modal to the parent view.

```
$('#inputNewBornKMCCheckbox').on('change', function (e) {
        var _this = $(this);

        // if checked
        if (_this.is(':checked')) {
            $('#inputNewBornKMC').modal('show');

        $("#SearchMother").on('click', function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/consultation/GetMothersDetailList',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: $('#frmSearchMother').serialize(), // it will serialize the form data
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('.firstDL').remove(); 
                        $('.subsequentPL').remove();

                        var rowNo = 0;
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            rowNo += 1;
                            $("#LoadMotherDetailsTable tbody").append("<tr Class='odd gradeX subsequentPL'>" +
                                        "<td>" + rowNo + "</td>" +
                                        "<td>" + data[i].paid + "</td>" +
                                        "<td>" + data[i].pidno + "</td>" +
                                        "<td>" + data[i].pname + "</td>" +
                                        "<td><button type='button' class='select btn btn-default' data-paid='" + data[i].paid + "'>Select</button></td>" +
                            "</tr>");
                        }

                        alert('LoadMotherDetailsTable list has been loaded.');

                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...');
                    }
                }); // end ajax

            });

            var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("GetMotherDetails", "consultation")';
            $("#LoadMotherDetailsTable tbody").on('click', '.select', function () {

                $.getJSON(baseUrl, { paid: $(this).data('paid') }, function (data) {

                    document.getElementById('#inputMotherMRN').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('#inputMotherMRNlabel').style.display = 'block';
                    $('#inputMotherMRN').val(data.paid);
                    $('#inputMotherName').val(data.pname);
                    $('#inputNewBornKMC').modal('hide');

                });
            });
}
```

Supposedly, after i click on the select button in the table row, the modal will hide, a label and a textbox will appear and the concerned data will be displayed in the label and textbox in the parent page.

But the modal won't close, the textbox and label won't appear and the data aren't passed either. Why is this happening? Could anyone lend me a hand please?

**UPDATE**

```
$.getJSON(baseUrl, { paid: $(this).data('paid') }, function (data) {

                    $('#inputMotherMRN').val(data.paid);
                    $('#inputMotherName').val(data.pname);                        
                });

document.getElementById('#inputMotherMRN').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('#inputMotherMRNlabel').style.display = 'block';
$('#inputNewBornKMC').modal('hide');
```

The data is passed but the modal won't close and the hidden textbox and label does not appear. When i check the debugger console, even after the line is moved, the problem seems to be still this `document.getElementById('#inputMotherMRN').style.display = 'block';` specific line.

This is the hidden textbox and label:

```
<label for="inputMotherMRN" class="col-sm-3 control-label" id="inputMotherMRNlabel" style="display:none">Mother's MRN</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
     <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="inputMotherMRN" name="inputMotherMRN" style="display:none" readonly>
</div>
```

Comment: Is you script being hit? (you need to debug it using your browser tools). And if so, what error message do you get in the console?

Comment: @StephenMuecke It says _TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null_. then when i press the link the sourcecode, it shows at line `document.getElementById('#inputMotherMRN').style.display = 'block';`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I think i get it. I tried putting the `document.getElementById(...)` outside of the json and now the data is passed to the textbox. Thanks. Just two problems left, the modal won't close after i click the button select in the row and the hidden textbox&label don't appear

Comment: You have not shown your html. We have no idea if your have an element with `id="inputMotherMRN"`. And why are you mixing jquery and vanilla javascript like that? - it can be just `$('#inputMotherMRN').val(data.paid).show();`

Comment: @StephenMuecke That works now! Infinite thanks! :D

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry but i just realized, when i tried to query inside the modal, it works only the first time. When i try to uncheck and recheck the checkbox and input values into the textbox in the modal for search query(for the second time), it gives an "ajax submit failed." Why is this?

Comment: Again, you have not shown the relevant code. I have no idea what your controller code is doing. I do not know why your making an ajax call when its both checked and unchecked, or why you have `$("#SearchMother").on('click', function () {` inside the `$('#inputNewBornKMCCheckbox').on('change', function (e) {` function which makes no sense.

Comment: @StephenMuecke this is so weird, after asking you i retried the search query, now it works, not just on first time search. 0.o ignoring what i just said, will it cause my code to be buggy if i do it the way i do it now? I was just thinking that i put the `on('click'..)` inside the `on('change'...)` because i wanted them to be executed/called only if the checkbox is checked. Should the `$("#SearchMother").on('click', function () {` be outside the `$('#inputNewBornKMCCheckbox').on('change', function (e) {`?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: @StephenMuecke alright thanks :)